# Use color from theme attr don't work as expected

Tags: java, android, styles, themes, attr

I want use color from theme's attr for `textView.setTextColor()`. I found method:

```
public static int getColor(int attr, Resources.Theme theme) {
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    theme.resolveAttribute(attr, value, true);
    return value.data;
}
```

and it doesn't work for some `TextView` as expected. For example, it work with `R.attr.colorPrimary` (text become **Red**) and doesn't work with `R.attr.colorPrimarySelector` (my custom attr) (`colorPrimarySelector` is blue, but text become transparent)

But if I use:

```
public static int getColor(int attr, Context context) {
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr, value, true);
    return ContextCompat.getColor(context, value.resourceId);
}
```

and it works fine. 
I don't understand, why first work for some View or some attr and don't work for another, and what the difference between return values.
Context is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution! If color setted as `colorStateList` - first method always return `Color.TRANSPARENT`. So, the best solution is used second method

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution for change text color is use color from resource file.

if you are in activity:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

if you are in fragment:

```
textView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Comment: If you want to change theme in runtime - it is not a solution